# Scala 2.9.3 postgres driver

Tags: database, scala, jdbc, jvm, jdbc-postgres

I'm using Scala 2.9.3 because that's the latest version Spark Project requires. However I cannot find a database driver for Postgres that supports 2.9.3. All of them support up to 2.9.2 and then jump to 2.10.0.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Is there really a Scala spezific PostgreSQL driver? I' aware only of the "generic" JDBC driver which does not depend in the Scala Version.

Comment: Have you tried them?  2.9.3 is just a maintenance release, it should be binary compatible with anything requiring 2.9.2.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with the libraries I was trying to add... it seemed like all the dependancies I added couldn't be resolved by SBT.